# syntax of using Viewbag in aspx view engine?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I know ViewBag is used in Razor view engine but not sure how to access viewBag's dynamic properties in aspx view engine.

As I want to put text inside Html.ValidationSummary() through Viewbag I am using the following syntax but getting error ***"has no applicable method named 'ValidationSummary' but appears to have an extension method by that name. Extension methods cannot be dynamically dispatched. Consider casting the dynamic arguments or calling the extension method without the extension method syntax."***

Syntex:

```
<%= Html.ValidationSummary(ViewBag.ValidationSummary)%>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is complaining because `ValidationSummary` has no single parameter overload that takes a parameter of type `dynamic`; that is what `ViewBag` properties are.  Cast the property to a string.

```
<%= Html.ValidationSummary((string)ViewBag.ValidationSummary)%>
```

Comment: thanks,

I even tried before 
<%= Html.ValidationSummary(ViewBag.ValidationSummary.ToString())%>
but it did not work, can you please tell why, I was considering .ToString() being coming form Object class should be available here as well. I was getting above error doing that.

Comment: @user188129 `ToString()` does not work because you are receiving a **compile-time** error.  The type `dynamic` does not have a method `ToString()` even if the type at **run-time** will be a type that does have a definition for it.

Comment: Thanks @asymptoticFault. I am sorry I am asking too much you already have helped me but will be highly appriciate if you please can comment on my point as well. I suppose .ToString() being coming from Object class should not available in all types, even if it is a dynamic type as I was considering dynamic types would be inharited from Object type as well. Any guidance please.

Comment: @user188129 Have a look at this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd264741.aspx  There is too much for me to explain in a comment.  There is also this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx